# React native Google Signin Issue in Ios

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native, google-signin

[image]I am using this library For Google-signin : [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin)

After Integration of the library in ios I am getting an error while running in a real device:

in signalhandler.cc file

```
No member named '__rip' in '__darwin_arm_thread_state64
```

Note: It is running fine in simulator. I am getting the error only when running in real devices.

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` and `yarn install`

Comment: @PritishVaidya not worked getting same error :(

Comment: Make sure that you follow the exact procedure as of that library documentation

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I tried to run from xcode on a physical device...I saw this solution on github and it worked for me
Change this line:

```
return (void*)context->PC_FROM_UCONTEXT;
```

to

```
return NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below steps which required to do in xCode:

1) In Libraries folder **RNGoogleSignin.xcodeproj** is there or not. If not, then drag from node module folder.

2) Add **libRNGoogleSignin.a** lib into **Link Binary** in **Build Phase**.

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: I am not able to found "libRNGoogleSignin.a" in my folder . Which step I am missing ?

Comment: Have you drag the RNGoogleSignin.xcodeproj into your project?

Comment: Go to the Build Phase --> Link Binary --> libRNGoogleSignin.a

Comment: From Which folder ? libRnGoogleSignin.a is not showing anywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you when I was trying to run an out of box React Native app on my iPhone X. Which I am running Mojave on a MacBook Pro using Xcode 10.

I had no issues running a base React Native app in simulator but have an issue running it with a physical device. While looking in the libraries, I was not able to find **RNGoogleSignin.xcodeproj** that *Nirmalsinh* motioned.

So, after some digging I found this thread. 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16106

It looks like there is a serious bug with Xcode 10 and React Native.

They suggest to take line 78 where it throws the error and just return null and it fixes that error. As below.

```
ucontext_t *context = reinterpret_cast<ucontext_t *>(ucontext_in_void);
return NULL;
```

Don't know why that line would throw and error or what that context is actually for, but returning NULL allows me to compile it on the physical device.

Don't know if this fixes your problem, but it might help others who stumbled on to this like I have.

And if it is because its missing  **RNGoogleSignin.xcodeproj**, then there needs to be another way to add that library in as it was there in my folder. Unfortunately, I don't know where you could find it to install it.